# XML и Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, синтаксический-анализ

У меня есть API на сайте, который выдает строку с XML, при передаче GET запроса.

Я умудрился сохранить данный XML с сайта в файл, с помощью такого кода:

```
  Memo1.Text:=Idhttp1.get('http://justknow.ru/xml.php?key=c9fce58afb5d208b953b41e134dc6229&func=get&fid=1');
    memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('xml.xml');
```

Но теперь не хочется самому парсить XML. Есть ли стандартные компоненты, которые помогут разбить весь XML код в какой-нибудь массив или БД?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TXMLDocument` с вкладки `Internet`.

---

**UPD0**

Пример [тут](http://postera.ru/delphi/rasparsivanie-xml-s-pomoshy-txmldocument/), документация [тут](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/XMLDoc_TXMLDocument.html).

Comment: я его вставил, но что-то не понял что дальше делать

Comment: дальше парсит надо. Что значит "что делать" ?

Answer (score 1):

Есть неплохая библиотека `SimpleXML`, можете попробовать.

Официальный сайт не работает, тут одна из ссылок, что нашёл в гугле: [SimpleXML](http://delphisite.ru/components/simplexml).